# Redirect To Action not carrying exception data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have  a base controller which takes care of excption handling . so all my actions in the controller simply delegate to the action in basecontroller.

```
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", ex);
            }
```

my base controller action is

```
   public ActionResult Error(Exception ex)
```

Teh problem here is excpetion details are getting clreared in Error Action in base controller. I think these are getting cleared during redirection.

Comment: There are other ways to handle exceptions in MVC. You might want to look into handling exceptions globally. Also if you use redirection the http response code won't reflect the pages real state which is bad for semantics.

Comment: Agree with you.But, I've to show specific errror page depending on each exception type.

Comment: And you can have you're error specific page. I'm finding it hard to find a good example. Check out this one though http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html

Comment: This one is good too http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/01/error-handling-and-customerrors-and-mvc3-oh-my.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, when you do a redirect you're basically sending a 302 to the browser so the data is lost.

A possible way to temporarily save the data is saving it in the tempdata:

```
TempData["error"] = ex;
```

After that you can retrieve it in the Error-method:

```
Exception ex = TempData["error"] as Exception;
```

Note: the tempdata is for short-lived data and can be especially handy in redirect-scenarios

Answer (score 1):

In MVC 3 and higher exceptions caused inside the MVC pipeline had be handled, and include exception data, by using an `HandleErrorAttribute` and Error Views.

You would register the filer like so

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) 
{ 
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

And use a view similar to the following

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo        
@ViewBag.Title = "Error"; 

<h2>An Error Has Occurred</h2> 

@if (Model != null) { 
      <p>
           @Model.Exception.GetType().Name<br /> 
           thrown in @Model.ControllerName @Model.ActionName
      </p> 
}
```

For a more detailed introduction see these articles:

http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/aspnet-mvc-handleerror-attribute-custom.html

http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/01/error-handling-and-customerrors-and-mvc3-oh-my.aspx